# Unable to move a QGraphicsRectItem with mouse click

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyqt4

I have QGraphicsRectItem() defined as follows

```
def create_blocks(self):
    """
    Creates block rectangles and adds them to scene.
    """
    for i in range(self.nrows):
        line_block = []
        for j in range(self.ncols):
            block = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 100, 100)
            block.setPos(j * 100, i * 100)
            self.scene.addItem(block)
            line_block.append(block)
        self.block_array.append(line_block)
```

These rect items are filled in the following way:

```
def fillData(self):
    """
    Fill puzzle blocks with numbers and remove SPACER block.
    Fills puzzle block with color - zigzag
    """
    color1 = Qt.lightGray
    color2 = Qt.gray
    last_color = color1
    color_table = {}

    # generate dict with color for each number (1-lgray, 2-gray, 3-lgray, etc.)
    keys = xrange(1, 16)
    for key in keys:
        color_table[key] = last_color
        last_color = color1 if last_color == color2 else color2

    for j in range(self.ncols):
        for i in range(self.nrows):
            block = self.block_array[i][j]
            blockBoundRect = block.boundingRect()
            block.mousePressEvent(Qt.LeftButton)
            num = self.init_data[i][j]
            if num == self.SPACER:
                self.scene.removeItem(block)
                continue
            else:
                text = str(num)
                block.setBrush(QColor(color_table[num]))

            textItem = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(text, block)
            font = textItem.font()
            font.setPixelSize(50)
            textItem.setFont(font)
            textItemBoundRect = textItem.boundingRect()
            new_x = blockBoundRect.width() / 2.0 - textItemBoundRect.width() / 2.0
            new_y = blockBoundRect.height() / 2.0 - textItemBoundRect.height() / 2.0
            textItem.setPos(new_x, new_y)
```

> block.mousePressEvent(Qt.LeftButton)

with this line I was trying to enable the click to rectangles and I am not able to do so as of now. I need help for some one to point me where to write the logic of, if button clicked and next to blank position, move the rectangle.

I am trying to make a 15 puzzle game in python, I already have the backend code connected to the GUI and the solver part works fine. I have no prior experience with QT, I am basically a python script writer noob.

Answer (score 0):

You should set these flags after item creation:

```
block.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
block.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
```